# how to close tab and remove this file from buffers

Tags: buffers, neovim, tabbed-user-interface

I often use `:tab sball` to open all buffers as tabs, but sometimes after doing so I would like to close the tab and remove file from buffers at the same time. How can I achieve that?

I know already that if I open a new tab with
`:tabe` and don't save it- it close it with buffer using: `q!`.

Is there something similar to close tab and buffer at the same time?

I'm using neovim (NVIM 0.1.3-dev).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`:bd` will do that.

From the [documentation](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/windows.html#:bdelete):

```
:[N]bd[elete][!]            *:bd* *:bdel* *:bdelete* *E516*
:bd[elete][!] [N]
        Unload buffer [N] (default: current buffer) and delete it from
        the buffer list.  If the buffer was changed, this fails,
        unless when [!] is specified, in which case changes are lost.
        The file remains unaffected.  Any windows for this buffer are
        closed.  If buffer [N] is the current buffer, another buffer
        will be displayed instead.  This is the most recent entry in
        the jump list that points into a loaded buffer.
        Actually, the buffer isn't completely deleted, it is removed
        from the buffer list |unlisted-buffer| and option values,
        variables and mappings/abbreviations for the buffer are
        cleared.
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm sorry- I don't know how I could have missed that...